# Nodejs: import class and its constructor in jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am noob with JS and I can't figure how to instantiate one of my objects in this **jest** unit test (backend / nodejs project)

**project structure**:

```
appi/
    src/
        configFactory.js
        ...
    test/
        configFactory.test.js
        ...
    package.json
```

### Using `require`

**configFactory.js**

```js
class ConfigFactory {
     constructor(index_mapping){
        this.mapping = index_mapping
    }
}
```

**configFactory.test.js**

```js
const ConfigFactory = require('../src/configFactory.js')
var fs = require('fs');


test('some test', () => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname +'/__mock-data__/Mappings/mappings_ac.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const factory = new ConfigFactory(data);
    });
});
```

This ends up with a `TypeError: ConfigFactory is not a constructor`

### Using `import`

```js
class ConfigFactory {
     constructor(index_mapping){
        this.mapping = index_mapping
    }
}

export default ConfigFactory
```

```js
import ConfigFactory from "../src/configFactory"
```

ends up with `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I tried to add `"type": "module"` to **package.json** but I feel that I am missing an important point

Comment: The decision if you are using CJS or ES6 should not be dictated by jest, what is your choice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was not properly exporting my class for CJS:

```js
class ConfigFactory {
     constructor(index_mapping){
        this.mapping = index_mapping
    }
}

module.exports = ConfigFactory
```